# For the random variable $X$ with density function:

Tags: probability, density-function

Given the PDF
$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
4x,  & 0<x< \frac{1}{2} \\
4-4x, & \frac{1}{2}<x\leqslant1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

(A) Determine the cumulative distribution $F(x)$

(B) Determine $P(\frac{1}{3}< X \leqslant \frac{1}{2})$

I don't know how to do this, I know I have to either derive or integrate for A, but I don't know which of the two results to use to find X in B.

Answer (score 1):

(A) The Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) is defined as
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x dy\ f(y)\ .
$$
So for $0< x< 1/2$
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x dy\ 4y=2x^2\ ,
$$
and for $x\geq 1/2$
$$
F(x)=\int_0^{1/2}dy\ 4y+\int_{1/2}^x\ dy(4-4y)=-2 x^2+4 x-1\ .
$$
Note that the CDF is right-continuous at $x=1/2$, is increasing and saturates at $1$ as it should.

(B) The probability $P(\frac{1}{3}< X \leqslant \frac{1}{2})$ is obtained by integrating the PDF $f(x)$ between the corresponding bounds
$$
P\left(\frac{1}{3}< X \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_{1/3}^{1/2}dx\ f(x)=\int_{1/3}^{1/2}dx\ 4x=\frac{5}{18}\ .
$$

Comment: For (b), one can also make use of the CDF obtained in (a), and simply find $P(1/3 < X \leq 1/2) = F(1/2)-F(1/3)$.